# ¿Porque no me deja usar una imagen generada en otro hilo para la UI usando Invoke en WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, ui

Estoy intentando mostrar un video que se graba en directo usando un `ImageBrush` que se tiene que actualizar decenas de veces por segundo. El problema es que despues de generar un mapa de bits en un hilo secundario al establecerla como imagen del `ImageBrush` me salta esta escepción : `System.InvalidOperationException:'El subproceso que realiza la llamada no puede obtener acceso a este objeto porque el propietario es otro subproceso.'`

Buscando en internet siempre me pone lo mismo que tengo que tengo que usar `Dispatcher.invoke(Action)` pero lo estoy usando y no cambia nada. Este es mi codigo:

```
//Tened en cuenta que todo esto está dentro de un hilo que no es el de la UI
//Recurso es una propiedad del objeto que engloba a los dos metodos

private void OnActualizacionImagen() //Este es el metodo que debería Actualizar la imaen 
{
    Action accion = () => ContenedorImagen.Fill = new ImageBrush(recurso);
    Dispatcher.Invoke(accion); //Aqui es donde salta la escepcion
}

public void GeneraImagen() //Aquí se genera la imagen (Esto está dentro de un bucle While pero no pasa de la primera vuelta)
{
    Bitmap mapaBits = new Bitmap(300, 300);
    Graphics captura = Graphics.FromImage(mapaBits);

    captura.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300));
    captura.Dispose();
    recurso= CapturaPantalla.loadBitmap(mapaBits);

    OnActualizacionImagen();
}
```

La razón por la que estoy generando esta imagen en otro hilo es porque si dejo el bucle while dentro del hilo principal la UI se queda pillada.

Comment: No podes acceder a un objeto que esta en otro thread... Estas generando una imagen? tal vez tengas que guardarla en disco para poder compartirla? o meterla en un objeto dentro de la ui principal?

Comment: @gbianchi el problema es que como tiene que hacerlo decenas de veces por segundo creo que la opción de guardarla en disco no es una buena idea. La segunda opción de meterla dentro de un objeto de la UI principal como sería?

Comment: Coloca el Invoke dentro del método GeneraImagen() anidando la llamada de OnActualizacionImagen()

Comment: Puede probar lo que dijo Leodev.. Yo deberia tener un analisis mucho mas profundo y complejo de lo que tratas de hacer, para tratar de darte una solucion... asi como esta, no se como es que generas decenas de imagenes por segundo, a menos que estes grabando la pantalla.. y en ese caso, que tendrias que actualizar con esas imagenes de la UI principal?

Comment: @gbianchi En mi código se ve. la funcion Graphics.FromImage() lo que hace es tomar una captura de pantalla y en los comentarios pone que está en un bucle while con el que intento dar la impresión de que es una grabación de pantalla. Y con esas imagenes había que actualizar el fondo de un control Rectangle (Es la funcion OnActualizaImagen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el método `Dispatcher.Invoke()` hace que se ejecute una acción desde el Hilo de la UI y la escepción no era provocada por que no se pudiese acceder al control sino porque no me deja utilizar un objeto generado en otro hilo como propiedad de uno de los controles de la UI. La solución que he encontrado es que genere el BitmapSource dentro del hilo de la UI con la imagen generada en el hilo secundario.

```
//Tened en cuenta que todo esto está dentro de un hilo que no es el de la UI
Bitmap mapaBits;

private void OnActualizacionImagen() //Este es el metodo que debería Actualizar la imaen 
{
    Action accion = () => ContenedorImagen.Fill = new ImageBrush(CapturaPantalla.loadBitmap(mapaBits));
    Dispatcher.Invoke(accion); //Aqui es donde salta la escepcion
}

public void GeneraImagen() //Aquí se genera la imagen (Esto está dentro de un bucle While pero no pasa de la primera vuelta)
{
    mapaBits = new Bitmap(300, 300);
    Graphics captura = Graphics.FromImage(mapaBits);

    captura.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300));
    captura.Dispose();

    OnActualizacionImagen();
}
```